# Need to upgrade Azure VM Standard HDD to SSD?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, ssd, azure-storage

I've got an email from Azure : "Adjust your disk throughput or upgrade to premium disk storage. You’re receiving this email because you’re running infrastructure as a service virtual machine (VM) workloads on a Standard HDD or Standard SSD Disk in Azure Storage, and your disk traffic exceeds 60 MB/s."

Background: The VMs are used in a service and they're going to get shut down and replaced in a few months. Can I leave the VMS unchanged? Any comments? Thanks, Peter

Comment: What did they say would happen if you do not upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably leave the vm's unchanged but the disks are being throttled and your service(s) could be affected by that. If you have unmanaged disks the disk performance is regulated by the VM size and you could scale up the VM's. If you are using managed disk you can scale up the disk itself.

I would recommend you to migrate to managed disk if you have unmanaged disk.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-unmanaged-to-managed-disks

```
$rgName = "myResourceGroup"
$vmName = "myVM"
Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName -Force
ConvertTo-AzureRmVMManagedDisk -ResourceGroupName $rgName -VMName $vmName
```